# Pseudo RF in embedded boards

Tags: audio, rf, embedded, trace

I noticed that wifi-capable embedded boards integrate the RF into the board design instead of having a separate, add-on wifi card. They have meshes that are etched into the board and the rest of the board, along with the other ICs, are RF shielded by metal plates.

So this got me wondering, on some embedded boards that have wide pcb etches and traces, can these traces be made to oscillate highly enough, in an analog way to create a somewhat wifi interface? I'm talking about semi-powerful embedded boards capable of running OS's, like Raspberry Pi, some e-book readers, etc.

I know that it's unlikely for any traces aside from audio will have any analog signals, or can be hacked, to do so but can it happen?

Comment: (1) Please use proper English capitalization.  (2) If you have links to the boards that you are referring to, then post the links (or pictures).

Answer (score 1):

You can build an antenna on a PCB quite easily. However, if you look more closely on the other side of the board to a PCB antenna, there is a gap in the ground plane. The ground plane on normal PCBs will absorb emitted RF energy, so you can't repurpose an existing board that wasn't designed to do this. In fact boards are specifically designed *not* to unintentionally radiate RF as FCC/CE certification prohibits this.

What you can do is stick an antenna on a pin and radiate signals from there: http://makezine.com/projects/make-38-cameras-and-av/raspberry-pirate-radio/ (technically violating FCC rules, but it's very unlikely anyone will notice)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily violate FCC rules.  It would be regulated as an intentional radiator.

Answer (score 0):

The WiFi or other RF signals will be produced in ICs - tracks on the board may be used as antennas, but by themselves won't produce or receive RF signals.  It is highly unlikely that a trace would be used as both an antenna and as an digital signal or power track.